How to read "audience" from caller in Keycloak
I am using Keycloak v25.
The caller will set "audence" in the token request.
grant_type: "client_credentials"
client_id: "my-client-1"
client_secret: "<client secret>"
audience: "https://myapi.example.com"

How do I get the audience value into "aud" of the resulting JWT token, for example
{
  "exp": 1718809393,
  "iat": 1718809093,
  "jti": "3813a93e-47b1-468d-aa4c-47c236462ce7",
  "iss": "http://localhost:18080/realms/MyKeycloak",
  "sub": "2f605b7b-4a27-467a-a090-bc3de1102873",
  "aud": "https://myapi.example.com",
  "typ": "Bearer",
  "scope": "",
...
}

I tried adding a Client Scope which has "Audenice" mapping. But it is showing
{
  "exp": 1718809393,
  "iat": 1718809093,
  "jti": "3813a93e-47b1-468d-aa4c-47c236462ce7",
  "iss": "http://localhost:18080/realms/MyKeycloak",
  "sub": "2f605b7b-4a27-467a-a090-bc3de1102873",
   "aud": "c93ad476-7d19-41cf-b766-50065391aeae", <-- Random generated value
  "typ": "Bearer",
  "scope": "",
...


